# How to auto format code on file save in KDevelop 5.2

Tags: formatting, ide, kdevelop

I try to play with KDevelop 5.2 on Windows 10 and try to auto format code on CTRL+S
Now I add custom source formatter (clang-format) and it works on click - Edit -> Reformat Source, but how to format code on file save operation?